# ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); ^ Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

```
const seedRouter = express.Router();

seedRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await Product.remove({});
  const createdProducts = await Product.insertMany(Data.products);
  res.send({ createdProducts });

  await User.remove({});
  const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(Data.users);
  res.send({ createdProducts, createdUsers });
});

export default seedRouter;
```

```
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\Laxman website\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\Laxman website\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12) 
    at ServerResponse.json (F:\Laxman website\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15) 
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\Laxman website\E-commerce\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:162:21) 
    at file:///F:/Laxman%20website/E-commerce/backend/routes/seedRoutes.js:15:7
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

app is crashed and it returns with the error above 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular error is caused by trying to send more than one response to the same request.  In your particular case, you are calling `res.send()` twice in the same request.  You can't do that as `res.send()` ends the request.

We don't know what you're trying to accomplish in your request handler, but it appears you can just remove the first `res.send({ createdProducts });` since you're already sending that data in the second one.

You also need a `try/catch` around your `await` so you catch promise rejections and can send an error response.

```
seedRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      await Product.remove({});
      const createdProducts = await Product.insertMany(Data.products);

      await User.remove({});
      const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(Data.users);
      res.send({ createdProducts, createdUsers });
 } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.sendStatus(500);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is because of sending **multiple responses** in a single request.
you are using `res.send()` in your GET request.